# Invalid Procedure call when creating a pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

I was told to try to separate the creation of the cache and table.  That worked in getting rid of some of the errors.  Now I am getting the invalid procedure call.  I've looked to see if other solutions can solve the issue, but I cannot figure it out.  I am running office 365 if that matters.  Here is my code.

thanks!

```
Sub Create_101102_pivot_CFG_MV_CL()


Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("TTB - Movements - CFG_CL")

Set DSheet = wb.Worksheets("101-102 F")

LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

Set PSheet = wb.Worksheets("Pivot 101-102 Production")

Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:="'Pivot 101-102 Production'!R2C2", TableName:="101102F_Pivot Table")
```

Comment: Side note: the docs recommend using a `String` instead of a `Range` for `SourceData` in [`PivotCaches.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcaches.create).

Comment: Then I think `TableDestination` should be passed a `Range`, not a `String`, in [`CreatePivotTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcache.createpivottable).

Comment: Try `TableDestination:=PSheet.Range("B2")`